# Getting entity attribute from CRM - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I'm using fetchXML to query MS CRM and everything seems OK except when I try to retrieve an attribute of an entity that is a unique identifier.

```
Guid contactID = entity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("sb_contactid");
```

Results in:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

When I inspect the entity before trying to get the attibute values I can see the value (and also that is a 'entityReference' is this relevant?).

[image]

[image]

I have also tried:

```
var contactID = (Guid)entity.Attributes["sb_contactid"];
```

Other entity attributes of various types are retrieved without issue and as above, can see the value of the attribute when inspecting the entity - how do I get it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `sb_contactid` is `EntityReference`. You won't be able to cast this to `Guid` type.

But you can get the `Guid` from the `EntityReference`.

`Guid contactId = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("sb_contactid").Id;`

Comment: That's exaclty what I was doing wrong, seems so obivous now.  Thanks for pointing that out!